# How can I query all entities that have an associated entity in Hibernate Query Language?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hql

I'm struggling to understand how can I query all products that have specified category association.
[image]

I might need something like this

```
select p.* from product p
inner join product_category pc on p.product_id = pc.product_id
inner join category c on pc.category_id = c.category_id
where c.name = :categoryName;
```

but in HQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you use the following mapping:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
class Product
{
   @Id
   @Column(name = "product_id")
   private Long id;

   @ManyToMany
   @JoinTable(name = "product_category",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "category_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    )
   private List<Category> categories;

   // getters/ setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
class Category
{
   @Id
   @Column(name = "category_id")
   private Long id;

   @Column(name = "name")
   private String name;

   // getters/ setters
}
```

you can use the following HQL:

```
select p from Product
join fetch p.categories c
where c.name = :categoryName
```